# Which JS version supports plane detection for Augmented Reality?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore

I am making an AR app for Android which uses a `WebView` to host an URL, it should detect a plane and put a 3D object on it.

Can anyone tell me which JS supports plane detection for both Horizontal and Vertical plane detections?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a version issue. It's the issue of `WebXR Device API`. At the moment it officially supports VR features only. If you need AR features, you must use a `WebXR Hit Test API` as well.

Excerpt from [Augmented reality for the web](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/06/ar-for-the-web):

> In Chrome 67, we announced the `WebXR Device API` for both augmented reality (AR) and virtual reality (VR), though only the VR features were enabled. VR is an experience based purely on what's in a computing device. AR on the other hand allows you to render virtual objects in the real world. To allow placement and tracking of those objects, we just added the `WebXR Hit Test API` to Chrome Canary, a new method that helps immersive web code place objects in the real world.

The immersive web samples use one created just for the demos called [Cottontail](https://github.com/immersive-web/webxr-samples/tree/master/js/cottontail), and [Three.js](https://threejs.org) has supported WebXR since May 2018.

Hope this helps.

Comment: what do you mean with "It supports VR only"? Do you know if there is still no support for AR features in webXR? I want to build an AR App using WebXR. In the API jungle, I'm not exacty sure which I have to use for  Hittesting. Another approach is here: https://github.com/mozilla/webxr-polyfill/tree/e4fa65a9bdb09e8e753014436d2f5b76c949e047/examples/hit_test